# populating display tag in a popup using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, spring-mvc, displaytag

In my application,i am using jQuery-Ajax to get the list to be populated in a popup. I am getting a list in the javascript code, like [["1","abc"],["2","bcd"]].. I am using a display tag in the popup section to display the popup.

My javascript function is like

```
function getData()
{
     $.ajax({
            url: 'getLists.jav',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    alert("Success"+value);
                });
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert("Error");
            }
          });
}
```

I need my display tag to populate with that data using javascript. Is it posible?

Comment: the list? a popup? display tag? please be more specific.

Comment: I need to populate the display tag,which im given in a popup div with a list from java script. The flow is like..
1. getting list in javascript.
2. Giving that list to display tag for populating.
3. display popup

Comment: i still don't understand. I'm not familiar with a `<display>` tag.

Comment: just go through this. http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are populating dropdowns are smaller tables doing this in javascript is fine. but if the table table more number of columns then its little difficult. In the below case, in  function(index, value) value is the domail object which has attributes of code, value, codeValue and its getters and setters. i used to refresh the table of contents by rendering JSp since it has more number of columns. Let me know your other technologies(Java/Struts/.Net) so that i can help you in that.

```
$.ajax({
            type :"POST",
            url  :methodArguments[1]+value,
            data :"&random="
                    + Math.random(),
                    dataType: "json",
            success : function(data) {
            $.each(data.lstJSONValues, function(index, value){
            $("#"+methodArguments[2]).append($("<option/>").attr("value", value.code).text(value.valueCode)); 
               });
            },
            error:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```